# threading.py._release_save & socket.py.accept cpu time

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, profiling

I'm creating an app of which I like to limit its resource footprint as much as possible.
I noticed my app is consuming by average 4% cpu usage on a low load and although that doesn't necessarily mean a bad thing, I was wondering where exactly this comes from.

I started to use a profiling software (yappi) and while all threads not seem to spend much time there are 2 exceptions:

```
name                                 #n       tsub       ttot       tavg
Thread         1402.. ../lib/python2.6/socket.py.accept:19 340      678.6799.. 
..bmit_listene 1402.. ..n2.6/threading.py._release_save:21 5032     932.8961..
```

Are these methods/classes known to be "resource intensive"?
Do you have any performance improving tips related to these?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Timings for the blocking calls in profilers are not very meaningful. When a blocking call is made that thread is suspended and other threads run, when blocking call returns back the time spent in other threads is also added to the total time of the called function. See this: Multithreaded Statistics for Yappi

Update: v0.62 supports CPU time profiling which effectively solves all the problems related with multithreaded profiling of blocking functions.